# question about input validation after element loses focus

Tags: javascript

I started learning javascript, and I am trying to make a little project to play around.
I want to validate that the input field for username contains only letters (uppercase or lowercase) and when the value is correct, to outline the field with a color. (I don't care about the design, i care about functionality since it's purpose is for learning).

I have this code: https://jsfiddle.net/7zcv4g1m/1/

```
const userField = document.querySelector('#user .user');
const passwordField = document.querySelector('#password .password');

const regEx = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/g;

function checkUser() {
  // userField.setAttribute('class', 'user');
  let userText = userField.value.substring(0, userField.value.length);
  let expr = regEx.test(userText);
  if (expr == true && userText.length > 0) {
    userField.setAttribute('class', 'user test');
  } else {
    userField.setAttribute('class', 'user');
  }
}

userField.addEventListener("focusout", checkUser, false);
```

My problem is this: at first run, if I click on the element and type a correct text, it outlines the input as expected when I focusOut of the element. The issue is when I click back in the element and just click somewhere outsite of the element to trigger focusout event, without modifying anything in the text. Somehow, my regex condition (the expr variable in the code) is considered to be false, instead of being true, and it turn the element's output back to grey instead of green. If I click back in and after out, it turns back the input border to green.

I don't understand why is this happening and where I made a mistake. Or maybe I wrote the code wrong. If anyone can please give me a hint, will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's caused by `regEx.test(userText)`. This should work:

```
function checkUser() {
  // userField.setAttribute('class', 'user');
  let userText = userField.value.substring(0, userField.value.length);
  let expr = userText.match(regEx);
  if (expr && userText.length > 0) {
    userField.setAttribute('class', 'user test');
  } else {
    userField.setAttribute('class', 'user');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

delete modificier g in RegEx, like as

```
const regEx = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/
```

Comment: It works, thanks. I read more carefully what g does. I guess it was in some conflict with ^? If i read correctly, ^ should start from the start for the strig